# can I modify SQL Server so that there are no implied rollbacks

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback

Context:
I have an application that is being migrated from a Jet to a SQL Server back end. Part of that application includes user-customisable "searches". The searches start a transaction on the current connection, execute a series of statements provide some results and then commit the changes. If there is an error, then I send a "ROLLBACK TRAN" and provide an error message.
Unfortunately I have fallen afoul of implied rollbacks. Some errors, for example creating a view with an unnamed column, will create an implied rollback, which rolls everything back to the first "BEGIN TRAN". This causes two problems. The first problem is minor: when I execute a "ROLLBACK TRAN" (or rollback to a save point) in response to the error (which I will need for non-implied-rollback errors) I get an error message telling me I can't rollback because there are no transactions. No big deal, I can identify and ignore these.
The major problem I have is if I am editing and testing a search - this error will mean that any uncommitted changes to the search will also be rolled back and the form will be in an inconsistent mode (essentially it will think it is in Edit Mode, but really it is in View mode). All of this is currently done under a single connection and rewriting it will be a pain.
I've done a bit of research into the matter and I think I may have to move the current search to another designated table and execute on a separate connection, but I was wondering if there was a more effective solution.
Question:
Can I modify SQL Server's behaviour so no errors will cause an implied rollback?
If I am editing a search, should I move the search to a designated table, then execute from there in a separate connection (that way I can access the current search without affecting the prior version)?
Is there some other, more optimal approach?

PS: apologies for the wall of text and if I've breached netiquette, most of my simple questions have already been answered, I've never had to ask a question before. Hail to the all-knowing Google.

Comment: why a `SELECT` (to me search = select) should start a transaction? i'm not sure i got the whole picture but the transaction should be simply removed.

Comment: These reports often do a lot of background data processing - inserting and manipulating data into temp tables or passing data to other searches. It turns out that adding more info made my question less understandable.

Comment: a good option could be consolidating. when heavy and/or complex data handling is involved a separate database where data is copied onto at regular intervals offpeak (daily?) with some degree of intermediate elaboration, may give the required data 'freshness' while avoiding the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Unfortunately these are legacy reports that were originally written for a Jet database and now need to be supported (with minimal or no modification).  Rewriting them from scratch isn't a feasible option.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I'm looking for isn't possible. SQL is designed to automatically rollback to the first BEGIN TRANSACTION when some errors occur. There is an option - a recommended option - to change SQL's default behaviour so all errors are rolled back automatically and not just some.
set xact_abort on.